# webpack 4 dynamic import remote module

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

I am implementing a library in es6 that needs to load some modules from a remote destination. I want to support a scenario where the library itself is hosted on domain **a.com** but it needs to be able to download some modules dynamically from domain **b.com**

I use Webpack 4. I was thinking to use dynamic imports a la:

```
import(moduleSpecifier)
.then((module) => { //do something with module } );
```

Unfortunately this only works in case the lib and module are hosted on the same domain.

Anyone knows what would be the best strategy in this case?

Comment: What error are you getting when importing remote modules? Could it be a CORS error?

Comment: It results in a HTTP 404; it is assumed that the module is hosted on the same domain as the main module

Answer (score 0):

There is no best strategy for this case yet. Since webpack is seen as a bundle system in the first place, it does not expose a parameter to configure dynamic chunked imports.

However, there are solutions like the [share loader](https://github.com/MrFrankel/share-loader) or even simple plain fetch requests that can eval bundled javascript code like [in this example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150#issuecomment-308427725):

(taken from the example code)

```
 fetch(appUrl).then(response => 
   response.text()).then(function(text) {
   /* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
   let define = (fn) => fn();
   /* eslint-disable no-eval */
   let importedModule = eval(text);
 });
```

The limitation of such solutions is that they require the imported javascript to be bundled separately.